# Java cache file not found Windows 10 on Cargonizer Agent startup

Tags: java, windows-10

*Windows 10, Java Version 8 Update 241*

I have a problem when running Cargonizer Agent program. When I try to open it, I get this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\X220\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\8\3b87adc8-6efc8d15 (Systemet finner ikke angitt fil)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And in fact I don't have any cache files. I tried to reinstall Java, but it didn't work. It's obvious, because cache files can't magically occur.

Answer (score 0):

Previous Cargonizer Agent update caused this problem (CS said so), updating program fixed it!